# No module named django.core.wsgi with nginx, uwsgi and virtualenv

Tags: python, django, nginx

uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
vhost = true
plugin = python
socket = /tmp/pjwards.sock
master = true
enable-threads = true
processes = 2
wsgi-file = /home/ubuntu/workspace/ward/www/fb_archive/wsgi.py
virtualenv = /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/fb_archive
chdir = /home/ubuntu/workspace/ward/www/fb_archive
touch-reload = /home/ubuntu/workspace/ward/www/reload
```

wsgi.py

```
import site

import os
import sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

from mezzanine.utils.conf import real_project_name

site.addsitedir('/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/fb_archive/lib/python3.4/site-packages')
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/ubuntu/workspace/ward')

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE",
                      "%s.settings" % real_project_name("fb_archive"))
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

uWSGI does not work by `ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi`.
I use nginx, uwsgi and virtualenv with python3.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/ward/www/fb_archive/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing the import before you've added your virtualenv to the pythonpath, so naturally the module can't be found. Move the import to just before the `get_wsgi_application()` call itself.

Comment: Thank you. your right. Unfortunately, I face another problem. It works with python2. So, I edit `plugin = python` to `plugin = python3` in uwsgi.ini. It can't load plugin.